# About the boundary conditions in the finite potential wall

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

Suppose we have a finite potential wall with a "depth" $V=-V_0$ and a radius of $a=1.5$ fm. The exercise now states that $\Psi(r) = u_0R(r) = u_0\frac{u(r)}{r}$, where $$u(r) = \begin{cases} A\cdot \sin(kr)+B\cdot \cos(kr)&r \leq a \\ C\cdot \exp(-\alpha r)+ D\exp(\alpha r)& r\geq a.     \end{cases}$$

We needn't even prove this, but are supposed to determine $B, C$, and $D$ by considering the boundary conditions at $r=0$ and $r=\infty$, and the continuity condition at $r=a$.

Okay, if we consider $r\to\infty$, then I obtain for it $D=0$. But for $r\to 0$, I am not quite sute yet: $$\lim \limits_{r\to\infty}R(r)= \lim \limits_{r\to\infty}\frac{A\cdot \sin(kr)+B\cos(kr)}{r}.$$ However, $A\sin(kr)/r\to Ak$ for $r \to 0$, while the cosine-term is ill-defined in the limit and therefore $B=0$, I guess. What, then, is my boundary condition at $r=0$?

The exercise sheet is in German; nevertheless, I include it since I am not quite sure myself. First, there appears a vector arrow and then it is omitted.

[image: Task]

Comment: Is this in 1D, or for a radial coordinate in 3D? (This is essential information and *needs* to be included in the post, from the get-go.)

Comment: If this is a radial problem the probability density $r^2 R^2(r)$ must go to $0$ as $r\to 0$ so this excludes the $\cos(kr)/r$ function.

Comment: In what sense is $r=0$ a boundary?

Comment: ad Pisanty: I edited my post. ad ZeroTheHero: I agree with you that the cos(kr)/r-function must vanish. ad probably_someone:I supposed that the wall goes from x = 0 to x = a (or r = 0 to r = a), so that $r = 0$ would be a boundary ... But I find the task vague as that it doesn't specify where the potential wall lies

Comment: @MathIsFun i order to ping someone, you have to use the @ symbol before their name; note that you're limited to pinging one user per comment

Answer (score 1):

The “boundary condition” at $r=0$ is just that the wave function is continuous. As you noted, $$\sin(kr)/r \to k$$ in this limit, so it is continuous, but $\cos(kr)/r$ is certainly not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

This is variation on particle in finite potential well problem, but we have only condition:

$V=-V_0$ for $x: -a\leq x \leq a$

instead $x: 0 \leq x \leq L$ as often it is in similar excersises. Moreover we don't know the potential values outside the well. Probably outside is $0$ as inside is $-V_0$ (negative value) and I should be good assumption.

So, at $r=0$ boundary condition is:

$V(r=0)=-V_0$

May it help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well

One more thing, in your post is incorrect: $A\sin(kr)/r\to Ak$ for $r \to \infty$. It goes to $0$. $A\sin(kr)/r\to Ak$ for $r\to 0$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I corrected it!